# mathjax with jquery fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mathjax

In a html page with mathematical formulas using MathJax, I'm trying a smooth transition in the change from one formula to the another.

Here is the current code, that you can [test here](https://jsfiddle.net/LnfL020r/2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- https://jsfiddle.net/LnfL020r/2 -->
<title>math guided training</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      mgtMult: "",
      mgtSelect: [ "\\bbox[10px,border:1px solid red]{#1}", 1],
    }
  }
});    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>


<style> 

    .results {
    display: flex;
        height: 4cm;
    position: relative;
    }


#fadeBox,
#visibleBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>    
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
    var math = null;   // the jax element 
    var box = null;    // the box math is in
    var formula = "1+2x^3";

    var SHOWBOX = function () {
    var a = $('#box').html();
    var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
        dstDiv.html(a);
    }

    var SHOWBOX_FADE = function () {
    var a = $('#box').html();
    var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
    var fadeDiv = $('#fadeBox');

    fadeDiv.html(a);
    fadeDiv.fadeIn(2000,function() {
           dstDiv.html(a);
       fadeDiv.hide();
        });
    }

    var REFRESH = function () {  
    QUEUE.Push(
          ["Text",math,formula], // == math.Text(formula), [ method, object, args... ]
          SHOWBOX
        );
    }

    var REFRESH_FADE = function () {  
    QUEUE.Push(
          ["Text",math,formula], // [ method, object, args... ]
          SHOWBOX_FADE
        );
    }

    //  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
        QUEUE.Push(
          function () {
        math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("box")[0]; // returns a MathJax.ElementJax
        math.Text(formula);
            SHOWBOX();
          }
        );

   setTimeout(function(){
     SHOWBOX();
   }, 2000);

    window.changeIt = function() {
      formula = "1 + 2 { \\left( y + 4 \\right) } ^ 3 ";
      REFRESH_FADE();
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

        <div id="box" style="visibility:hidden; font-size: 500%; height:1px;"> 
        \( \)
        </div>

        <div class="results">

            <div id="visibleBox" style="font-size: 500%;">
        Loading ...
            </div>

            <div id="fadeBox" style="font-size: 500%; display:none;">
            </div>

        </div>

        <button onclick='changeIt()'/>click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is:

The second formula has different height than the first one, due to the parenthesis. For this reason, the common part "1 + " of the second one is printed slightly down respect to its print in the first formula.

That produces an effect of borrow during the transition. I want that the "1 + " part, common to both formulas, doesn't moves when changing from first to second.

Any hint?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

Made little change in fadeIn and fadeOut

```
fadeDiv.html(a);
dstDiv.fadeOut(1000,function() {
       dstDiv.html(a);
   fadeDiv.fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

[Forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vctdau1/)
Please comment if transition is not up to expection

**EDIT**
Updated With requirement

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0vctdau1/2/)

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var QUEUE = MathJax.Hub.queue;  // shorthand for the queue
    var math = null;   // the jax element
 var mathdef = null;   // the jax element
    var box = null;    // the box math is in
 var defaultformula = "1+";
    var formula = "2x^2";

    var SHOWBOX = function () {
 var a = $('#box').html();
 var def = $('#defbox').html();
 var fixedDiv = $('#fixed');
  fixedDiv.html(def);
 var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
        dstDiv.html(a);
    }


    var SHOWBOX_FADE = function () {
 var a = $('#box').html();
 var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
 var fadeDiv = $('#fadeBox');

 fadeDiv.html(a);
 dstDiv.fadeOut(1000,function() {
           dstDiv.html(a);
    fadeDiv.fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }

    var REFRESH = function () {  
 QUEUE.Push(
          ["Text",math,formula], // == math.Text(formula), [ method, object, args... ]
          SHOWBOX
       );
QUEUE.Push(
          ["Text",mathdef,defaultformula], // == math.Text(formula), [ method, object, args... ]
          SHOWBOX
       );
  
    }

    var REFRESH_FADE = function () {  
 QUEUE.Push(
          ["Text",math,formula], // [ method, object, args... ]
          SHOWBOX_FADE
       );
    }

    //  Get the element jax when MathJax has produced it.
        QUEUE.Push(
          function () {
     math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("box")[0]; // returns a MathJax.ElementJax
  mathdef = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("defbox")[0]; // returns a MathJax.ElementJax
  mathdef.Text(defaultformula);
     math.Text(formula);
            SHOWBOX();
          }
        );

   setTimeout(function(){
     SHOWBOX();
   }, 2000);

    window.changeIt = function() {
      formula = "2 { \\left( y + 4 \\right) } ^ 2";
      REFRESH_FADE();
    }


}//]]>
```

```css
.results {
 display: flex;
  height: 4cm;
 position: relative;
}


#fadeBox,
#visibleBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      mgtMult: "",
      mgtSelect: [ "\\bbox[10px,border:1px solid red]{#1}", 1],
    },
 Macros: {
      mgtMult: "",
      mgtSelect: [ "\\bdefbox[10px,border:1px solid red]{#1}", 1],
    }
  }
});    
</script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

    
<div id="defbox" style="visibility:hidden; font-size: 500%; height:1px;padding-top:10px"> 
  \( \)
        </div>

        <div id="box" style="visibility:hidden; font-size: 500%; height:1px;padding-left:200px"> 
  \( \)
        </div>

        <div class="results">
   
   <div id="fixed" style="font-size: 500%;margin-top:50x">
    Loading ...
            </div>
            <div id="visibleBox" style="font-size: 500%;padding-left:100px">
  
            </div>

            <div id="fadeBox" style="font-size: 500%; display:none;padding-left:100px">
            </div>

        </div>

        <button onclick='changeIt()'>click me</button>


  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is an interesting option, but it hides completely the first formula before print second one. The target is that "1+" never moves nor disappears.

Comment: i don't know anything about mathjax. So I give suggestion  that render "1+" in the fixed div or container and remaining in another div or container. there you apply this logic to second container.I hope this will ease requirement

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work :

```
var SHOWBOX = function () {
      var a = $('#box').html();
      var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
      // apply margin for the first equation
      dstDiv.css({"margin-top":"2px"});
      dstDiv.html(a);
 }


var SHOWBOX_FADE = function () {
      var a = $('#box').html();
      var dstDiv = $('#visibleBox');
      var fadeDiv = $('#fadeBox');

    fadeDiv.html(a).fadeOut();
    fadeDiv.fadeIn(500,function() {
       dstDiv.html(a);
      // remove the margin for the second equation
       dstDiv.css({"margin-top":"0"});
             fadeDiv.hide();
    });
}
```

just applying a margin to counter the slight variance in top margin

Comment: Yes, in this case, the effect is exactly what is expected. However, in my computer I need to modify the margin from "2px" to "10px". The problem is then how to generalize this solution to any pair of formulas and any client computer configuration. In the real case, formulas are generated by a Java program.